# Removing item from DataGrid does not delete it from the database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I'm using vb2010 and Ms access 2007 for the database. I have a delete button which is not working properly. It only deletes the selected data in the datagrid but not in the database (access). Here is my code:

```
BotikaBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

I need also to delete the selected item in the database not just in datagrid.

Comment: You need to create function that delete data from database also.

Comment: Yeah, you need to work with the data source also. The `.RemoveCurrent` is just removing the current item from the grid control, so you must also call whatever delete/remove on the data source.